# Multiple puts on Google App Engine - all fail or all succeed?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a game server running on Google App Engine. Some of my HTTP requests result in multiple puts to different Models. So I have a user model and a game model for example and the one request may write to both. I am using python with the NDB database interface.

Is there a way to ensure both succeed or in the even that one succeeds and one fails to have them both fail? Transactions sounded like it might be the right thing but I'm not clear after reading the docs and it's talking about multiple requests and collisions.

I do see that a single put can take a list of entities but I don't see any mention of if one fails then they all fail behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, transactions are what you need.  You need to structure your data properly with Ancestors in order to write them all within a transaction though.

If any of the puts fail, none of the puts within the transaction get written.  Says so right in the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the ndb transaction docs which weren't nearly as clear as this one.  Makes more sense now.  I do need to use the xg=True flag as my data isn't structured properly for normal transactions.  I'm not clear on the downsides of this and if it's work re-arranging

Answer (score 0):

You can use XG transactions for update up to 5 entity groups (up to 5 object if you don't use parent-child model).

Every entity group (or object) have limit about 1 transaction/second.

ndb transaction: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions
limitation of xg transactions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Cross_Group_Transactions